# Using svn to work with a repository on Box hosted with rclone

Tags: svn, box, rclone

I have a local repository that I have moved to my Box drive (all on my work's PC running Windows, TortoiseSVN). My home machine runs Linux and I have used rclone to mount my Box drive, but when I use svn in the terminal it doesn't recognise my repository.

Is it a problem with svn? The way I setup rclone? The mount? I'm struggling to deal with this and it is fast becoming an insurmountable hurdle that will force me to move to Windows at home. I have also tried and failed to install Box drive using WINE.

The repository contains my PhD research, which I'd like to have swift access to at work, home or wherever my laptop is.

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a local repository that I have moved to my Box drive

Never host version-control repositories on Box, Dropbox OneDrive, Google Drive or similar services. You will corrupt the data this way.

Better deploy a server on a cloud VM (MS Azure, AWS) or use a hosted service.

Comment: It has worked so far, even when it was on OneDrive before that. I do think things will be less complicated if I use github... a hosted service is designed to do what I would like. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Just because it's worked so far doesn't necessarily mean it'll be that way forever. Even [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html) discourages using network drives. (Good luck on whatever you're researching btw ;))